# Tf has two or more unconnected trees

Tags: hector-quadrotor, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and I am trying to run the indoor example of the hector_quadrotor packadge. I followed the instructions ,ran the launch file (indoor_slam_gazebo.launch) and rviz and gazebo windows appeared. The problem is that rviz shows errors in the laserscan, map and robot model all of which are related to not having a transform and having two unconnected trees. I made an image of the tf tree and this showed two seperate trees: a world tree and a base_link tree.

How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161771/tf-has-two-or-more-unconnected-trees/) by [anonymous16901](https://answers.ros.org/users/16901/anonymous16901/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed the laser and robot model by setting the fixed frame parameter in rviz to base_link. The map still gives the error "no transform from [map] to [base_link]"

---

Originally posted by [anonymous16901](https://answers.ros.org/users/16901/anonymous16901/) with karma: 16 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-21**:
For the map to base_link you need to run a form of localization. such as slam_gmapping or amcl